# How do I insert exercises to google fit with name, calories and duration

Tags: java, android, google-fit

My app has hundreds different exercises available in database. 
Users can add them to their diary with the following data:

- name of an activity e.g. fishing, football etc
- duration of the exercise
- calories burned

When it's done I also want this data to go to the Google fit and show as a activity/workout.

I'm currently adding sessions to the Sessions api like so:

```
    //1 ACTIVITY DATASOURCE
    DataSource activityDataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context.getPackageName())
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            .setName(exercisename + " - activity")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    //2 CALORIES DATASOURCE
    DataSource sourceKcal = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context.getPackageName())
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .setName(exercisename + " - calories")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    //3 EXERCISE DATASOURCE
    DataSource sourceExercise = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(context.getPackageName())
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_WORKOUT_EXERCISE)
            .setName(exercisename + " - workout")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();


    DataSet activityDataSet = DataSet.create(activityDataSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = activityDataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_ACTIVITY).setActivity(FitnessActivities.OTHER);
    activityDataSet.add(dataPoint);

    DataSet kcalDataset = DataSet.create(sourceKcal);
    DataPoint kcalDatapoint = kcalDataset.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    kcalDatapoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).setFloat(kcal);
    kcalDataset.add(kcalDatapoint);

    DataSet exerciseDataSet = DataSet.create(sourceExercise);
    DataPoint exerciseDataPoint = exerciseDataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    exerciseDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DURATION).setInt(mins);
    exerciseDataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_EXERCISE).setString(exercisename);
    exerciseDataSet.add(exerciseDataPoint);


        // Build a session insert request
    Session session = new Session.Builder()
            .setName(exercisename)
            .setDescription("My Exercise Session")
            .setActivity(FitnessActivities.OTHER)
            .setIdentifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .setStartTime(startTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setEndTime(endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    return new SessionInsertRequest.Builder()
            .setSession(session)
            .addDataSet(activityDataSet)
            .addDataSet(kcalDataset)
            .addDataSet(exerciseDataSet)
            .build();

Fitness.getSessionsClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
            .insertSession(insertRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    // At this point, the session has been inserted and can be read.
                    Logger.d(TAG + "Speed Session insert was successful!");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    verifySession();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Logger.d(TAG + "There was a problem inserting the Speed session: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

My added exercise does appear in the Google Fit app with my custom name and the duration, however the calories value that I selected for it isn't showing.

Thanks

Comment: You may follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#insert_data) to insert data into the fitness history. You need to first create a `DataSet` instance. After you create a `DataSet` instance, use the [`HistoryClient.insertData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient.html) method to asynchronously add the instance to the user's fitness history. You may also check this [link](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/workout) on how to record a workout using the Fitness REST API.

Comment: I've read the documentation you linked several times, it only has basic examples of inserting and reading steps data etc. What I want to do is insert workout activities of type OTHER with my name, my calories and my duration. 

I'm already inserting certain DataSets as shown in my updated question above ^

Comment: did you found the solution? why calories not updated?

Comment: no, asked my boss to just not do that! can at least sleep now :) I highly recommend that "solution"